# How to store predicted classes matching the pre-vectorized X in Python Scikit-learn?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, prediction

I would like to use name to predict gender. And not just name but name features like extracting the "last name" as a feature derived from a name. My code's flow is as such, get data into df > specify lr classifier and dv dictVectorizer > use functions to create features > perform dictVectorization > training. I would like to do the followings but can't find any resources of how.

1) I would like to add the predicted classes (0 and 1) back into the original data set or the data set that I can see both the names and the predicted gender classes. Currently my y_test_predictions correspond only to X_test which is a sparse matrix.

2) How can I retain the trained classifier and use it to predict genders of a different data set with a bunch of names? And how can I just insert a name "Rick Grime" and have the classifier tells me what gender it predicts?

I have done something like this with nltk, but can't find any example or references to do this in Scikit-learn.

Codes:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series
    import numpy as np
    import re
    import random
    import time
    from random import randint
    import csv
    import sys
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
    from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as sk_confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
    from sklearn import cross_validation 

    data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8")
    df = DataFrame(data)
    dv = DictVectorizer()
    lr = LogisticRegression()

    X = df.raw_name.values
    X2 = df.name.values
    y = df.gender.values

    def feature_full_name(nameString):
        try:
            full_name = nameString
            if len(full_name) > 1: # not accept name with only 1 character
                return full_name
            else: return '?'
        except: return '?'

    def feature_full_last_name(nameString):
        try:
            last_name = nameString.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
            if len(last_name) > 1: # not accept name with only 1 character
                return last_name
            else: return '?'
        except: return '?'

    def feature_name_entity(nameString2):
        space = 0
        try:
            for i in nameString2:
                if i == ' ':
                    space += 1
            return space+1
        except: return 0

    my_dict = [{'last-name': feature_full_last_name(i)} for i in X]
    my_dict2 = [{'name-entity': feature_name_entity(feature_full_name(i))} for i in X2]


    all_dict = []
    for i in range(0, len(my_dict)):
        temp_dict = dict(
            my_dict[i].items() + my_dict2[i].items()
            )
        all_dict.append(temp_dict)

    newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(newX, y, test_size=0.3)

    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_test_predictions = lr.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use some of scikit-learn's built-in tools to split the dataframe, vectorize the names, and predict the results. Then you can add the predicted results back into the test dataframe. For example, using a small set of names as an example:

```
data = {'Bruce Lee': 'Male',
        'Bruce Banner': 'Male',
        'Bruce Springsteen': 'Male',
        'Bruce Willis': 'Male',
        'Sarah McLaughlin': 'Female',
        'Sarah Silverman': 'Female',
        'Sarah Palin': 'Female',
        'Sarah Hyland': 'Female'}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['name', 'gender']
print(df)
                name  gender
0    Sarah Silverman  Female
1        Sarah Palin  Female
2  Bruce Springsteen    Male
3       Bruce Banner    Male
4          Bruce Lee    Male
5       Sarah Hyland  Female
6   Sarah McLaughlin  Female
7       Bruce Willis    Male
```

Now we can use scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer` to count the words in the names; this produces essentially the same output as what you've done above, except it doesn't filter on length of name, etc. For ease of use, we'll put this in a pipeline with a cross-validated logistic regression:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

clf = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV(cv=2))
```

Now we can split our data into a train/test set, fit the pipeline, and then assign the results:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, train_size=0.5, random_state=0)

clf.fit(df_train['name'], df_train['gender'])

df_test = df_test.copy() # so we can modify it
df_test['predicted'] = clf.predict(df_test['name'])

print(df_test)
                name  gender predicted
6   Sarah McLaughlin  Female    Female
2  Bruce Springsteen    Male      Male
1        Sarah Palin  Female    Female
7       Bruce Willis    Male      Male
```

Similarly, we can just pass a list of names to the pipeline and get a prediction:

```
>>> clf.predict(['Bruce Campbell', 'Sarah Roemer'])
array(['Male', 'Female'], dtype=object)
```

If you want to do more sophisticated logic in your text vectorization, you can create a custom transformer for your input data: a web search for "scikit-learn custom transformer" should give you a decent set of examples to work from.

---

Edit: here's an example of using a custom transformer to generate dicts from the input names:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class ExtractNames(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, *args):
        return [{'first': name.split()[0],
                 'last': name.split()[-1]}
                for name in X]

    def fit(self, *args):
        return self

trans = ExtractNames()

>>> trans.fit_transform(df['name'])
[{'first': 'Bruce', 'last': 'Springsteen'},
 {'first': 'Bruce', 'last': 'Banner'},
 {'first': 'Sarah', 'last': 'Hyland'},
 {'first': 'Sarah', 'last': 'Silverman'},
 {'first': 'Sarah', 'last': 'Palin'},
 {'first': 'Bruce', 'last': 'Lee'},
 {'first': 'Bruce', 'last': 'Willis'},
 {'first': 'Sarah', 'last': 'McLaughlin'}]
```

Now you can put this in a pipeline with a `DictVectorizer` to generate sparse features:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

pipe = make_pipeline(ExtractNames(), DictVectorizer())

>>> pipe.fit_transform(df['name'])
<8x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Finally, you could make a pipeline which combines these with a cross-validated logistic regression and proceed as above:

```
clf = make_pipeline(ExtractNames(), DictVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV())
clf.fit(df_train['name'], df_train['gender'])
df_test['predicted'] = clf.predict(df_test['name'])
```

From here, if you wish, you could modify the `ExtractNames` transformer to do more sophisticated extraction of features (using some of your code from above), and you end up with a pipeline implementation of your procedure, but lets you simply call `predict()` on an input list of strings. Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way I can use pipeline with DictVectorizer instead for my example above? I have more features that require me to use DictVectorizer.

Comment: Yes, you can put ``DictVectorizer`` in a pipeline in the same way that I did with ``CountVectorizer`` above. You would just pass the list of dicts to ``clf.fit()``. Even better would be to write a custom transformer to ingest a list of strings and create the dicts that are then passed to ``DictVectorizer``. The pipeline can have as many steps as you wish.

Comment: Sorry, would you please show it in code for 'just pass the list of dicts to clf.fit()', I am not very advance in scikit-learn. Or let me know a reference which I can learn from will be much appreciated.

Comment: Above I defined a pipeline with ``CountVectorizer`` as the first step and passed it a list of strings. You could define a pipeline with ``DictVectorizer`` as the first step and pass it a list of dicts.

Comment: I added an edit with an example of this – hope it's helpful.

Comment: I accepted yours as the answer since it works in your example, but my actual example is a little more complicated so hopefully I figure out how to tweak so fit my purposes. Can I ask, say in addition to 'class ExtractNames', I need another class 'class ExtractLocation', do I go 1) pipe = make_pipeline(ExtractNames(), ExtractLocation(), DictVectorizer()), 2) clf = make_pipeline(ExtractNames(), ExtractLocation(), DictVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV()), and 3) clf.fit(df_train['name'], df_train['location'], df_train['gender'])?

Comment: Not exactly – a pipeline is a linear process: the output of one estimator becomes the input of the next. If you want to use more features, you could write a single transformer that accepts the full dataframe (rather than just the names column) and outputs all the features you're interested in. Alternatively, you could use a [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#featureunion-composite-feature-spaces) to combine name and location data from different transformers. Best of luck!